# redirect to url with parameters django python

Tags: python, django

AoA,
   I am trying to redirect to view with parameters but unable to get the parameters

here is the code, it is working fine if I use `(r'^search/$',... )` instead

**url.py**

```
url(r'^search/\?item=(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'contacts.views.search_Page', name='search_view'),
```

**views.py**

```
def search_Page(request,item_id):                   #GET Method
    return redirect('home_view')
```

it gives me no error, but django unable to find the page or view(404 page), why?

Using the URLconf defined in TestApp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$
^home/$ [name='home_view']
^logout/$
^save/$
^edit/$
^create/$
^account/$
^callback$ [name='callback']
^profile/$ [name='profile_view']
^search/\?item=(?P<item_id>\d+)$ [name='search_view']
^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, search/item=4, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 3):

Paths go in `urls.py`. Handling query parameters goes in the view.

**url.py**

```
url(r'^search/$', 'contacts.views.search_Page', name='search_view'),
```

**views.py**

```
def search_Page(request):
    address = request.GET['item'] # or GET.get('item', '') if the parameter might not exist
    print address
```

Comment: then how can I pass parameter from the some previous view?

Comment: i want to use query string from template
search/?item=5
like this

Comment: Then use `request.GET.item` in the template. Make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.request`.

Comment: The URL that you redirect to must contain what ever query parameters want. You can do this from this view.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your response. Its another headache to find the parameter, first I have to find the specific view I am calling, like the url.py is unable to find search view, if passed with parameter( look at the debug log above) but when I use the search view without any parameter, works fine

Answer (score 0):

Wrong regexp in urls.py. 
If you want to handle urls like `search/?item=123/`. Use this:

```
^search/\?item=(?P<item_id>\d+)/$
```

But better to use following with your view:

```
^search/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$
```

Comment: But original url was search/?item=123. I mean with '?'

Comment: it not working with any
127.0.0.1/search, nor with 127.0.0.1/search/?item=5

Comment: It works with 127.0.0.1/search/?item=5/ If you want 127.0.0.1/search/?item=5 - then use ^search/\?item=(?P<item_id>\d+)$